# Processing 50 GB of data with Pyspark on laptop with 2GB of memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to analyze a month's worth of tweets pulled from the Twitter API.  I plan to filter each day's tweets and keep only those that mention specific company names.  Furthermore, my directory structure is organized by day (e.g., for month of September, I have separate folders 01 to 30 with their respective tweets).

Now, I want to test a model over the month of tweets using my laptop, and I know that a day's worth of tweets, but not much more, can fit into my laptop's memory.  The only way I could think to do this is by coding a for loop and throwing each folder into my model in sequence.  Like this:

```
for folder in folder_list:
    day = folder + '/*/*.json.bz2'
    day_DF = sqlContext.read.json(day)
    #model continues....
```

However, I eventually want to run the model on a cluster I've been told the looping is not scaleable/not the best way to utilize Spark's parallelism functionality.  So, can anyone suggest how best to structure the ingesting of the data so that it will scale up?  Also, is there any way for me to test the model on my local machine without using the loop?  I'd prefer to avoid using Spark Streaming--the tweets I have are already pulled down, so I'm not connecting to the API in real-time...

Comment: _I've been told the looping is not scaleable/not the best way to utilize Spark's parallelism functionality_ - a single machine with 2GB memory is neither. No matter how you structure this Spark won't a good choice here.

Comment: I'd suggest to run this on a small subset of the data on your laptop for testing. Unless you need a separate model for each folder, you'd probably want to load everything into a single DataFrame.